# Java How to find a value in a linked list iteratively and recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, iteration

I have a method that has a reference to a linked list and a int value. So, this method would count and return how often the value happens in the linked list. So, I decided to make a class,

```
public class ListNode{ 
 public ListNode (int v, ListNode n) {value = v; next = n;)
 public int value;
 public ListNode next;
}
```

Then, the method would start with a

```
public static int findValue(ListNode x, int valueToCount){
 // so would I do it like this?? I don't know how to find the value, 
 // like do I check it?
  for (int i =0; i< x.length ;i++){
    valueToCount += valueToCount; 
  }
```

So, I CHANGED this part, If I did this recursively, then I would have

```
public static int findValue(ListNode x, int valueToCount) {
  if (x.next != null && x.value == valueToCount {
     return 1 + findValue(x, valueToCount);}  
  else 
   return new findvalue(x, valueToCount);
```

SO, is the recursive part correct now?

Comment: ... and your question is 'would this work?'?

Comment: yes, I was wondering if this can work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow know where your list ends. Let's assume (as that's the easiest approach) that the last node has `next` set to null. You would then use this as check when to stop the iteration:

```
public static int findValue(ListNode x, int valueToCount) {
    ListNode currentNode = x;
    int count = 0;
    while (currentNode.next!=null) {
      if (currentNode.value == valueToCount) {
        count++;
      }
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The same approach can be used for recursive solution, except it's a bit messier because you'll need to pass your `count` as parameter to your recursive function call.

Comment: you could just add another `int` to your signature, make your `while` an `if` and change the `currentNode=currentNode.next;` to `return findValue(x,valueToCount,count);`

Comment: @Jacky, the example above has the counter in the `if`/`else` statement, the comment above gives you clues to adopt a recursive method.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hints, this really helped me understand more about it :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in your sample code:

```
return findValue(x, valueToCount +1);
```

You should be incrementing the count, not the value being searched for.  Also don't forget to move to the next node!  So this should be:

```
return 1 + findValue(x.next, valueToCount);
```

Comment: Java doesn't have tail-call elimination, so there's little point passing the count as an extra accumulator parameter.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but what about the if statement. I think its wrong right? should it be if(x.next == null && x.value != valueToCount) {
return 0; 
}
would that be right?

Comment: @Pete, valueToCount is the value being searched for, not an accumulator.

Comment: @Jacky, if(x.next == null...) will miss the first node and will not work on the empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Little Lisper path:

1. What is the result of null  -- null
2. What is find result of a normal node --

   ```
   if (node.value == aValue)
       return true;
   ```

   if found
3. else try next node recursively

   ```
   public boolean find(ListNode<T> n, T value)
   {
     if (n==null)
      return false;
     if (n.element.equals(value))
        return true;
     else 
       return find(n.next, value);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you will find that if you run your `findValue` method with a non-null `ListNode` you will trigger an infinite loop.  You will need to move your node to `next` on each recursion.